# How to block all OSX notifications coming from a specific website?

Tags: macos, notifications

I'm not sure how they do it, but I keep getting OSX notifications from a news website.

It doesn't matter if I go to System Preferences -> Notifications and remove the website from there, it comes back again after a short while.

Note that I never visit this website and I block almost all browser notification popups (I'm using Brave).

Is there any way I can completely block this pesky website? Could it be some malware?

Answer (score 1):

Brave doesn't use the the system's web push notification settings, it uses its own settings.

If you want to use the system's settings, switch to Safari.

If you want to fix Brave, go to Brave's settings page for web push notifications:

brave://settings/content/notifications

I know the notification window looks like it's coming from the OS, but it's really Brave that is receiving the web push notification from the website and relaying it to the OS.